# Delphi: Desalocar de componentes da memória

Tags: delphi

Em Delphi, quando se aplica um FreeAndNil() a um TForm,
os componentes criados em tempo de execução neste Form
também serão desalocados da memória,
sem a necessidade de aplicar FreeAndNil
também ao objetos criados em tempo de execução?

Obrigado!!

Answer (score -1):

Se na momento de criar os componentes você passou o owner dele sim.

Exemplo de como libera da memória:

```
LLabel := TLabel.Create(FormPaiDoComponente);
```

Exemplo de como NÃO libera:

```
LLabel := TLabel.Create(nil);
```